# Is it possible to limit the volume of fluid ejected from a mesh? 2.82

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation

I am working with some fluid simulations in 2.82 which I am planning to add to my scene. My goal is to create a fluid sim which looks like rain water flowing off a roof.

So far I have a cylinder set up as my inflow object inside its domain. I have the inflow initial velocity z value set to -.01. I thought this would give me a slow dripping or runny effect but the fluid still looks like it's coming full blast out of a hose. Is there a property in the settings that allows you to control the volume of fluid particles being released?

Comment: Smaller flow object makes less fluid,have a try.

Answer (score 0):

In the fluid simulation tab, the **domain** part, you should have **Fluid Particles** panel. Go there and set Generate to a more than zero value, like 0.5